# Can Javascript object key name be retrieved using reflection?

Tags: javascript, object, reflection

Given the object:

```js
const product = {
  food: true,
  clothes: false
}
```

is there a way to programmatically get the name of **some** key without using `Object.keys` or similar methods. Something like `product.food.getKeyName()` which would return a string `'food'`. I find that I often have to add object key names to some constants object like:

```js
const products = {
  food: 'food',
  clothes: 'clothes'
}
```

which is my primary motivation to figure out a programmatic solution.

Here's an example use case. I want to run over all keys of an object and have different behavior for each key:

```js
Object.keys(product).map(key => {
  if (key === 'food') {
    // do something specific for food
  }
})
```

but I don't want to write string literals like `'food'`.

Comment: If you're accessing the key using the key name, then why do you need a method to tell you what that key is (as you already know what it is)

Comment: You can achieve this using proxies. Read more about this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: It's not really reflection, just `Object.keys(foo)` or `product.food` as you're doing seem fine. Why isn't this a possible solution? More context might be necessary--it feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Thanks.

Comment: If you can write `product.food.getKeyName()`, you can just as well write `'food'`. If the `food` part is a variable somehow… you already have the variable containing the value `'food'`.

Comment: @deceze I added more context to the question.

Comment: *"Do something specific for food", "don't write string literals like 'food'"* — So… how else would you do something specific for food then? You want something like `if (key === product.food.getKeyName())`? And the point of that is?

Comment: @deceze yes exactly, I don't want tons of string literals in my code.

Comment: The only possibility is to use constants then.

Comment: Maybe you want to create an object which maps keys to functions which you can then execute: `{food: () => {...}, clothes: () => {...}}`, then to execute the function in your forEach you can use: `fnObj[key]()`

Comment: @deceze is the downvote and closure of the question really warranted?

Comment: Well, the direct answer to your exact question is *No*, there's no such thing. If you have a specific *goal* for why you want this (minification? not repeating strings?) then you'll need to tell us that, since there are different solutions for those goals.

Comment: @deceze I already stated the goal "but I don't want to write string literals like 'food'". Anyway I added the solution based on Enijar which does exactly what the question asked. I personally believe it's valuable information for others as well. If you decide to reopen the question I will post the solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @`Enijar`'s tip indeed it is possible to programmatically retrieve object keys names using Javascript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) API as follows:

```js
const product = {
  food: true,
  clothes: false
}

const proxy = new Proxy(product, {
  get: function(originalObject, objectKey) {
    if (originalObject.hasOwnProperty(objectKey)) {
      return objectKey
    }
    throw new Error(`The field '${objectKey}' doesn't exist.`)
  },
})

console.log(proxy.food) // logs 'food'
console.log(product.food) // logs 'true'
```